# Flask app page not responsive when using layout

Tags: html, css, flask

I am developing a web app and I'm using a navbar.html as layout in each page of my webapp with this code :

## eachpage.html :

```
{% extends 'navbar.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="titre_pages">
        <h2>PAGE TITLE </h2>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Everything works fine and my pages seems responsive bu when I reduce the size of my browser my navbar and my titles are overlaping. Should I add something between my navbar/layout and my html code to avoid this ?

Here is my page with a normal browser size :
[image: Normal behaviour]

Here is my page when I reduce the size of my browser :

[image: Size page at minimum]

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is to use media queries to serve different css/design for different viewport sizes. If you use bootstrap or something and bootstrap grid often you can have responsiveness handled for you. Also see below for standard practice instead of extending a nav bar we would create a base.html that would contain the entire layout including navbar. With this method of assigning blocks and including files you can over you can then extend from base.html and only over ride the body block or sidebar block as necessary.

```
<!-- base.html -->
<!html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <header>
  {% block header %}
    {% include 'navbar.html' %}
  {% endblock %}
  </header>
  <body>
  {% block body %}
    {% include 'index.html' %}
  {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```